# Aws AppSync - query for all items between two dates

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I want to query all the items between two dates using AWS AppSync.
This my resolver :

```
{
 "version" : "2017-02-28",
"operation" : "Query",
"index" : "userInfoDate-index",
"query" : {
    ## Provide a query expression. **
    "expression": "userInfoDate BETWEEN :start AND :end",
    "expressionValues" : {
        ":start" : { "S" : "${ctx.args.start}" },
        ":end" : { "S" : "${ctx.args.end}" }
    }
}

//Schema
type UserQuestionInfo @model {
  id: ID!
  userId: String!
  userName: String!
  userInfoDate : String!
  weight: String!
  height: String!
}

type Query {
   getWeightByCreatedAt(start: String!, end: String!): UserQuestionInfo
 }
```

But I am getting this error :

Query key condition not supported (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException)
I don't know what's wrong or this does not support between query.
Please help

Comment: Is there any reason not to use AppSync scalar date types https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html ?

Comment: please take a look here, this is not an issue with appSync 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830888/dynamodb-query-error-query-key-condition-not-supported

Answer (score 0):

Most probably too late but I had the same issue and figured out.

<strike>You cannot use `BETWEEN` for types that are not integers (whether `String` or Scalars like `AWSDate`).</strike>

EDIT: Sorry I'm wrong, you actually can use `BETWEEN` for `String` or Scalars like `AWSDate`. **But you need a dedicated secondary DynamoDB index (like `userId-userInfoDate-index`) with a hash key on another field like `userId` where you would look for the exact key, and the range key on `userInfoDate`**. The resolver would then look like:

```
{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "index" : "userId-userInfoDate-index",
    "query": {
        "expression": "userId =:userId AND userInfoDate BETWEEN :start AND :end",
        "expressionValues": {
            ":userId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.userId),
            ":start": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.start),
            ":end": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.end),
    }
}
```

}

That means of course you need another criteria in your query, like `userId`.

If you can't, you can also use a `Scan` query with two filters on the same key. But a `Scan` would probably be way slower than a `Query` since it would search on the whole table not using indexes.

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Scan",
    "filter": {
        "expression": "userInfoDate >= :start AND userInfoDate <= :end",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":start" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.start),
            ":end" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.end)
        }
    }
}
```